# OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive

Tags: python

I'm trying to move automatically files from `C:/` drive to `D:/` drive,

```py
import shutil
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
            new_destination = folder_destination+ "/" + filename
            #os.rename(src, new_destination)
            shutil.move(src, new_destination)

folder_to_track = '/Users/sia/Downloads/Telegram Desktop'
folder_destination = 'D:/test_folder'
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()
```

I encountered this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: '/Users/sia/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/13940616000112.pdf' -> 'D:/test_folder/13940616000112.pdf'
```

what should I do ?
thanks

Comment: You have edited @sj95126's suggested change into your question, but you haven't accepted their answer, or added any sort of comment, so it's not clear just what the current status of your question is.  Did the suggestion fix the problem, or leave it unchanged, or what?

Comment: I found out my mistake and edited the question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`os.rename()` won't move files across drives. Instead, try using `shutil.move`:

```
import shutil
shutil.move(src, new_destination)
```